# React native request issue

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, ip

How can i request to php file and connect database as sametime . 10.0.2.2 ip not working. I'm using windows .

127.0.0.1 ip is using local db . Then i can't use it to react-native XMLHtppRequest ajax ip.help me

Comment: Can you adjust your PHP backend to serve data as REST API and Fetch API to communicate with the mobile app.